# How to call / access a label in button action programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
//This is the label

let changeLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 170, width: 300, height: 21))

self.view.addSubview(changeLbl)

//This is the button

let submitButton = UIButton(type: .system) // let preferred over var here

submitButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction) , for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

self.view.addSubview(submitButton)

//and this is action of above button

func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {

}
```

I want to call the above label in the following button function? like

```
func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    changeLbl.ishidden = true
```

// want to access label here, but it's not working this way.
    }

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: i cant get access to the label in button function... @shallowThought

Comment: What exactly happens "i cant get access to the label "? Compile error? Runtime Error? Which?

Comment: no error , as i declared label in other function and i'm calling label in another function ,  i want to hide the label when i click on this buttonAction ... all i want this but i can't get acces to label ... i'm newbie to coding... @shallowThought

Comment: checkout my ans

Comment: Don't say vague things like "it's not working" or "I can't get access to label." Say something very specific like "The line `changeLbl.ishidden = true` in my `buttonAction()` function gives the compiler error <exact_error_message>`. And don't post code without the enclosing scope. Where is all that code before your `buttonAction` function located? Is it in some other method? If so, post the entire method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to Access `changeLbl` you need to define as instance variable like this way and give global scope inside the class.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var changeLbl : UILabel!
    var submitButton : UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         //This is the UILabel
        changeLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 170, width: 300, height: 21))

        self.view.addSubview(changeLbl)

         //This is the button
        submitButton = UIButton(type: .system) // let preferred over var here

        submitButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction) , for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(submitButton)

    }

    //and this is action of above button

    func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        changeLbl.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`changeLbl` is a local variable. It's only visible in the scope of the method where the label is created.

If you don't want to use an instance variable – which is the normal way – and there is only one `UILabel` you can get the label from the `subviews` array

```
func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    if let changeLbl = self.view.subviews.filter({ $0 is UILabel}).first {
       changeLbl.ishidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: That approach is fragile - and not recommended. If you later move the the label inside another view object, or into a UIStackView, it will stop working. Likewise if you later decide to change the label view from a `UILabel` to a `UITextField`.

Answer (score 0):

If You want access label then declare it Globally.
Below Code for that:

```
class LabelDemo: UIViewController{
     var changeLbl: UILabel!
     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         changeLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 170, width: 300, height: 21))
         changeLbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
         self.view.addSubview(changeLbl)

         //This is the button

         let submitButton = UIButton(type: .system) // let preferred over var here
        submitButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        submitButton.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 150, width: 50, height: 30)
        submitButton.setTitle("hide", for: .normal)
        submitButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction) , for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(submitButton)


     }
    func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        if changeLbl.isHidden {
            changeLbl.isHidden = false
        }else{
            changeLbl.isHidden = true
        }

     }
}
```

Comment: Class names like `labelDemo` should begin with an upper-case letter.

Comment: jignesh Vadadoriya provided a complete, correct answer first. What does your answer add to that one?